# Best way to return list of records to select during create/update in Rest API

Tags: json, rest, api, web-services

In our application, we have to provide set of options to select.
After creating the configuration for update, we have to give list of options and which is selected.

**Note:** this configuration inside some other entity.

What is the best way to return the options ?

1. API to return all the options inside the entity response and specify which is selected.

Example:

```
{
    "entity":{
        //ENTITY DETAILS
        "config":{
            "Option":[
                //ARRAY OF OPTION DETAILS and field to describe which is selected
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

2. One API to return all the options and another API to return only the selected one inside the entity response.

Example:

**return all the options**

```
{
    "config":{
        "Option":[
            //ARRAY OF OPTION DETAILS
        ]
    }
}
```

**return only the selected one inside the entity response**

```
{
    "entity":{
        //ENTITY DETAILS
        "config":{
            "selectedOption":{
                //OPTION DETAILS
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd take reference in [how HTML is offering selections](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp) and translate this concept into your design as this concept should be familiar to most of the users (or clients) already. You are of course free to specify your own approach. But in order to increase interoperability you should standadize your approach at some point with IANA so that it can be [lookup and implemented](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) by 3rd parties as well

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best way is to `return all the options inside the entity response and specify which option is selected`. The benefit of this can be seen in client side code. 
If we have two APIs let say one is returning all the options and other one is returning only selected options then your page would be slightly slow as you have to make 2 api calls to show values in a multi-select control.
But, by going with the approach, I am suggesting, only 1 call would be enough.
I think this would help.